# ArrayList pointing to new reference will it call the GC

Tags: java, android, arraylist, garbage-collection

If I have an ArrayList with several elements and I want to clear all elements should I:

- point it to a new reference? Will this call the GC? In Android calling the GC is not so good.
- call arraylist.clear(). Does clear itself call the GC to free the memory?

What about if the arraylist is really huge? I think clear has bad performance when the arraylist is huge. So it is better to point to a new reference and just let the GC do its work?

Comment: Actually, what the call to `clear()` does is iterate over the backing array and setting each entry to `null` (as well as resetting the `size` attribute). No call to the GC, no fancy stuff.

Comment: You have no control over when garbage collection occurs. However, if you have an `ArrayList` which you set `null`, *and there exist no other references to the objects contained the the list before nullifying*, then those objects become *eligible* for garbage collection when the JVM determines it is time.

Comment: "I think clear has bad performance" -  what are you doing there? Adding and removing billions of elements? I bet you don't

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Is it billions of elements that can call the GC in Android? Android memory for each application can really be small so what I am worried is what happens if I put the arraylist to null. Those objects are somewhere still occupying memory no? If there are a lot in multiple arraylists then GC can be forced to be called. Sure I can't control the GC but I think I can do as much as possible to prevent calling it

Comment: but the clear also puts the objects to null, which means the objects are still there somewhere, so the GC will be called anyways right? Then I can conclude that there is no real advantage to using clear or dereferencing the arrraylist?

Comment: Assuming reference has size of 8 byte, your list with 1M elements will be the size of 8 megabytes. Not that much.

Comment: @androidpotato7 "there is no real advantage" - if we speak about how soon GC will occur, then yes, both methods are equal. But dereference is faster, as was mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> point it to a new reference? Will this call the GC? In Android calling
>   the GC is not so good.

It won't. Usually GC is performed when there is not enough memory for new object allocations.

> call arraylist.clear(). Does clear itself call the GC to free the
>   memory?

Again no. Clearing the list will remove references from list to elements, that's all. Actual GC will be performed when needed.

> What about if the arraylist is really huge? I think clear has bad
>   performance when the arraylist is huge. So it is better to point to a
>   new reference and just let the GC do its work?

Time complexity of `clear()` is O(n). Pointing reference to another array list is O(1). So yes, it is faster but I've never seen that in real world applications.